# EF Linq : Update related table List with ID in Array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, optimization

I have an array with int values which represents ID

I have an entity (generated with EF) with a collection property wich represents a related table (1 to n)

I need to update this collection with the values in the array

Of course I can foreach the one then the seconde but I'm sure there is a better way to do that with Linq maybe ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you already start solving this task? Hint: opening Visual Studio will be good beginning. If you already started, then please show us your code and explain whats wrong with it

Comment: Hi Sergey, I don't have a problem that block me, I just try to learn EF and try to improve my code. Like I said, I use EF and I need to update an entity, this entity has linked data to a related table. I want to know how can I update the data in this related table with Linq and using List attached to the entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "one step" update command in EF, as far as I know. First you have to select your item, then change it's value and then save it. 2 db round trip (select and save).

But if your ID column is primary key or unique, then for every item, create new db object, set ID value and attach it (use attach method), change value and save it. 1 db round trip (just save). I prefer this for performance increase.

On the other hand, there are two open source library for one step update command. But they only support Ms SQL Server. I couldn't remember the names of the libraries.

Example for attach:

```
using (DataEntities context = new DataEntities())
{
    foreach (int ID in IDList)
    {
        TableName item = new TableName();
        item.ID = ID;
        context.TableName.Attach(item);
        item.IsDeleted = true; //Change a filed's value
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```